# Problema com cláusula IN

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou precisando usar a cláusula IN em uma situação na qual a parte do in é uma string.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM BLABLABLA WHERE 4 IN ('6,5,4')
```

Isso me causa esse erro:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '6,5,4' to data type int.
```

No meu caso real a string '6,5,4' vem de um campo do próprio banco de dados que não posso modificar, então eu teria que arrumar um jeito de, na minha query, convertê-lo para que ele ficasse (6,5,4) ou ('6','5','4'), assim o SQL conseguiria ser rodado.

Gostaria de saber uma forma de resolver esse problema sem denegrir muito a performance.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/03/splitting-strings-sql-server-2016-rescue/. Será que isto ajuda?

Comment: Acho que seria perfeito, mas pelo que entendi (e testei sem sucesso) esse STRING_SPLIT é uma função do novo SQL Server 2016, estou utilizando uma versão anterior.

Comment: Não pode ser: SELECT * FROM BLABLA WHERE campo LIKE '%4%'

Comment: Não pois também pegaria valor 34, 44 por exemplo.

Comment: Hmmm. Mas se o IN fosse aceito '34', '44' e '6.5.4' seria selecionados igualmente. Não?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução que encontrei foi utilizar o LIKE e vírgulas.

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
    BLABLABLA 
WHERE 
    ',' + '6,5,4' + ',' LIKE '%,' + CAST(4 AS VARCHAR) + ',%'
```

Assim a string principal fica nesse formato: ',6,5,4,' e meu número sempre estará nesse formato ',5,' deixando a busca com o LIKE confiável.